# How to do custom order by string using sequelize

Tags: reactjs, node.js, arrays, object, sequelize.js

How to do custom order by using sequelize

I need to sort array of objects retrieved from db as `ACTIVE, PENDING, INACTIVE`

How to do using sequelize

Tried

```
sortOrder = [[Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN status=PENDING THEN 1 ELSE 0 ASC`)]];
```

Comment: If the answer is working ,please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a custom order by using Sequelize, you can use the `order` option in your Sequelize query. However, it seems there is a small syntax issue in your example. You need to place the `ASC` outside of the `CASE` statement.

Here's the corrected example:

```js
sortOrder = [
  [Sequelize.literal(`CASE WHEN status='PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`), 'ASC']
];

Model.findAll({
  order: sortOrder,
  // other options...
})
  .then(results => {
    console.log(results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

In this example, the `Sequelize.literal` is used to inject raw SQL into the query, allowing you to create a custom ordering. The `CASE` statement is used to assign a custom order value based on the `status`, and then `ASC` is applied outside of the `CASE` statement.

Make sure to replace `'PENDING'` with the actual values you have in your database. Also, remember that the `order` option takes an array, so you can add more conditions if needed.

Note: Be cautious when using raw SQL in your queries to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities. Ensure that the values are properly sanitized or use Sequelize's parameterized queries when dealing with user input.